# Creating realtime alerts for stock quotes

Tags: websocket, server, mqtt, real-time, publish-subscribe

I want to create a realtime stock alert app where users can subscribe to specific stock instrument with target price. Once that target price hit, The subscribed user will be notified over the app.

A good example of such platform is Tradingview.com

For stock API's I will be receiving realtime stock quotes from My API vendor over.

As far my knowledge is concern, I'm looking at this app as Web socket OR MQTT pub/sub platform where users can subscribe to that specific instrument topic and get notified once stock price is hit.

But my knowledge is limited when it comes to thousands of users subscribing to thousands of alerts.

What technologies must be going at the backend for such kind of apps ? What must be the data flow ?

Comment: As it stands your question is far too broad, there is no specific technical question here.

Answer (score 1):

Bit late answer to this, I was working on something similar with all custom NodeJS server and instruments you want to subscribe on. It is very simple server and you can find it here https://github.com/markosole/yahoo-node-streamer

I am working on desktop App built on top of Electron which is used for subscribing to instruments, monitoring multiple instruments and creating visual and sound alerts for every instrument individually. I have not release Electron app source to the public yet.

Creating mobile app will be harder as it would require backround data and best bet would be using Flutter and Google Firestore to send alerts. Well this is very top level.. I will eventually make flutter app and share it on Github

Answer (score 0):

Overlooking the fact that there are literally thousands of apps out there that do all of this already....

Your best bet might be to do one of two things:

1)  Just send out the stock price and let the client app figure out the alert, or
2)  Have a back-end system that just sends out the alert to the specific customer when their price point is reached.

Option 1 is something that MQTT could easily do.  Option 2 could be done using MQTT, but its something of an overkill IMHO.  MQTT is built for applications where one node is publishing data, and many nodes are subscribing to that data -- hence Option 1 is more in line with what MQTT was built for.